# Including test in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I started to use PHPUnit, and in my first test I don't understand why I have to use `require "app/Slug.php";` instead of `require "../app/Slug.php";`

[image]

and this is the test code:

```
<?php

    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

    class SlugTest extends TestCase{

        public function test_render(){
            require "app/Slug.php";

            $slug = new Slug("My First Test");

            $this->assertEquals($slug->render(), "my-first-test");
        }
    }
```

I thought that I could use `require "../app/Slug.php";` to make it work. I even tested the route in the console but the code only works with `require "app/Slug.php";`

Does anyone know why?

Comment: How you run your test?

Comment: vendor/bin/phpunit tests/SlugTest.php --color

Comment: Composer should take care of loading your `Slug` class. What namespace is it in? Did you configure the autoloading in your `composer.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct behaviour, because you run tests from project root directory. So current work directory is project's root folder. `require` will try to include relative paths using current directory as base path.

If you use `require "../app/Slug.php";` then you should run `phpunit` from the `tests` folder.

Like this:

```sh
# that way it will work with "../app/Slug.php"
cd tests
./../vendor/bin/phpunit SlugTest.php --color
```

So, the base path is not where the file is lying, but where you run it from.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You Need To require app/Slag.php to load a class or code inside it and access it from test file.
but you can use composer to autoload your Classes via [psr-4](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) or [files](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files)